# Is there any way to download jxl and wp2 file formats in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-webview

**Help me to download JPEG XL (.jxl) and webp V2 (.wp2) not working in android**

I Have an app with android webview and when download button pressed it converts bloburl and saves image to internal folder.
I'm using file and FileOutputStream to save the file. It is working for image format like jpeg, jpg, png but it is not working for two image formats below

- JPEG XL (.jxl) and
- Webp V2 (.wp2)

```
var imageBytes = Base64.decode(base64, 0) //base64 derived from blobURL

var os: FileOutputStream? = null
try {
    requestFile = File("$downloadPath/$fileName.$fileType")
    os = FileOutputStream(requestFile, false)
    os.write(ImageBytes)
} catch (ex: IOException) {
    Log.d("TAG", ex.toString())
    throw RuntimeException("Error generating file", ex)
} finally {
    if (os != null) {
        os.flush()
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
            context, arrayOf(downloadPath.path), arrayOf("image/*")
        )
        os.close()
    }
}
```

Please find the error message :-

- **java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/imageApp/image_12345.jxl: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)**
- **java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/imageApp/image_67890.wp2: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)**